# postgres db shows too many connections .what is the reason. how to check connection in jmeter tool

Tags: postgresql, jmeter

Some times in my postgres db showing "sorry,too many connections" and our webpage also not working and shows blank.

I want to do load testing for my site.  How I resolve this issue and how I will check in jmeter tool to find out exact connection issue.

Comment: You're probably leaking connections in your connection pool, likely failing to close them in the application. Plus your app's connection pool max size is probably configured to be bigger than your PostgreSQL max_connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check your [max_connections](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-MAX-CONNECTIONS) entry in Postgres configuration. It defaults to 100, perhaps you need to increase it.
2. If the error occurs on a file upload - the same action can be simulated by JMeter, just provide a file via "Send Files With the Request" input of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler. See [Performance testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) guide for more details on simulating file upload events with JMeter
3. You can test your database separately. JMeter provides J[DBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler for it.

   - Download [Postres JDBC driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) and drop it to the /lib folder of your JMeter installation
   - Restart JMeter
   - Add [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) and specify database details (connection string, credentials, etc.) there
   - Add JDBC Request Sampler(s) and put your queries there
   - Add threads according to your anticipated load and run the test.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase max_connection and shared_buffers

in /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf

change

max_connections = 100
shared_buffers = 24MB
to

max_connections = 300
shared_buffers = 80MB

and restart postgresql db.

Answer (score 0):

Start by using this query to see which connections are staying open

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

that will give you a starting point for further troubleshooting

Comment: that's ok. I dnt know why i am getting this issue.already increased connection limit 100 to 1000 in db. while uploading huge data via excel sheet, it shows same error in postgres. How to repeat the same issue in jmeter tool. then only I find out where exactly error occur.

Comment: 1000 connections is generally too many for efficient operation. You will suffer a performance hit.